# How to setup payment method on creating checkout session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm using `stripe` as an payment integration in my app. I'm creating `session checkout` for the customer with using `mode=payment` because i want to get payment from the order, but how to save payment method of the customer with this checkout session?

Here is my code:

```
await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            unit_amount: 433,
            currency: "usd",
            product_data: {
              name: ""
            }
          },
          quantity: 1,
        }
      ],
      cancel_url: "",
      success_url: "",
      customer: customerID,
      mode: STRIPE_SESSION_MODE.PAYMENT,
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
    });
```

thanks to this in response i've got an `url` to the stripe payment form. Is there an option to save information about payment method of the customer for the future using? I know that I can use `mode=setup` but i want also to get payment from the `price_data`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can opt to save the created payment method to a Customer object for future on-session (or off-session) payments using the [`setup_future_usage` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-setup_future_usage):

```js
await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  line_items: [
    {
      price_data: {
        unit_amount: 433,
        currency: "usd",
        product_data: {
          name: ""
        }
      },
      quantity: 1,
    }
  ],
  payment_intent_data: {
    setup_future_usage: "off_session"
  },
  cancel_url: "",
  success_url: "",
  customer: customerID,
  mode: STRIPE_SESSION_MODE.PAYMENT,
  payment_method_types: ["card"],
});
```